# Hardware requirement for apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, infrastructure

I am building a production environment where I will be having Apache Kafka. I want to know the best hardware combination to have for better performance. I will be having 5000 transactions/second.

Answer (score 12):

You would need to provide some more details regarding your use-case like average size of messages etc. but here's my 2 cents anyway:

[Confluent's documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html#cpus) might shed some light:

> **CPUs** 
> Most Kafka deployments tend to be rather light on CPU
>   requirements. As such, the exact processor setup matters less than the
>   other resources. Note that if SSL is enabled, the CPU requirements can
>   be significantly higher (the exact details depend on the CPU type and
>   JVM implementation).
>
> You should choose a modern processor with multiple cores. Common
>   clusters utilize 24 core machines.
>
> If you need to choose between faster CPUs or more cores, choose more
>   cores. The extra concurrency that multiple cores offers will far
>   outweigh a slightly faster clock speed.

***How to compute your throughput***
It might also be helpful to compute the throughput. For example, if you have 800 messages per second, of 500 bytes each then your throughput is `800*500/(1024*1024) = ~0.4MB/s`. Now if your topic is partitioned and you have 3 brokers up and running with 3 replicas that would lead to `0.4/3*3=0.4MB/s` per broker.

More details regarding your architecture can be found in Confluent's whitepaper [Apache Kafka and Confluent Reference Architecture](https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/apache-kafka-confluent-enterprise-ref-architecture.pdf). Here's the section for memory usage,

> **ZooKeeper** uses the JVM heap, and 4GB RAM is typically sufficient. Too
>   small of a heap will result in high CPU due to constant garbage
>   collection while too large heap may result in long garbage collection
>   pauses and loss of connectivity within the ZooKeeper cluster.
>
> **Kafka brokers** use both the JVM heap and the OS page cache. The JVM heap is used for replication of partitions between brokers and for log
>   compaction. Replication requires 1MB (default replica.max.fetch.size)
>   for each partition on the broker. In Apache Kafka 0.10.1 (Confluent
>   Platform 3.1), we added a new configuration
>   (replica.fetch.response.max.bytes) that limits the total RAM used for
>   replication to 10MB, to avoid memory and garbage collection issues
>   when the number of partitions on a broker is high. For log compaction,
>   calculating the required memory is more complicated and we recommend
>   referring to the Kafka documentation if you are using this feature.
>   For small to medium-sized deployments, 4GB heap size is usually
>   sufficient. In addition, it is highly recommended that consumers
>   always read from memory, i.e. from data that was written to Kafka and
>   is still stored in the OS page cache. The amount of memory this
>   requires depends on the rate at this data is written and how far
>   behind you expect consumers to get. If you write 20GB per hour per
>   broker and you allow brokers to fall 3 hours behind in normal
>   scenario, you will want to reserve 60GB to the OS page cache. In cases
>   where consumers are forced to read from disk, performance will drop
>   significantly
>
> **Kafka Connect** itself does not use much memory, but some connectors buffer data internally for efficiency. If you run multiple connectors
>   that use buffering, you will want to increase the JVM heap size to 1GB
>   or higher.
>
> **Consumers** use at least 2MB per consumer and up to 64MB in cases of large responses from brokers (typical for bursty traffic).
>   **Producers** will have a buffer of 64MB each. Start by allocating 1GB RAM and add 64MB for each producer and 16MB for each consumer planned.

There are many different factors that need to be taken into consideration when it comes to tune the configuration of your architecture. I would suggest to go through the aforementioned documentation, monitor your existing cluster and resources and finally tune them accordingly.